# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning in prediction modeling script

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script that does some predictive modeling and uses Pandas data frames. The script is throwing a `SettingWithCopyWarning`, however the stack trace is pointing to the pandas library instead of my code.

I've narrowed down the line of code that's causing the warning.

How do I go about changing my code so this warning doesn't get raised?

I do not want to suppress this warning, I want to fix it.

Thanks

This is the line causing the warning

```
next_round_x.loc[:, feature_cols] = scaler.transform(next_round_x[feature_cols])
```

This is the warning that is being raised:

```
/home/ubuntu/environment/virtualenvs/predictions/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:966: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

Here is the full function for context

```py
def create_predictions():
    # Grab the cleaned AFL dataset and the column order
    afl_data = afl_data_cleaning_v2.prepare_afl_data()
    ordered_cols = afl_data.columns

    next_week_odds = get_next_week_odds("data/weekly_odds.csv")
    fixture = get_fixture("data/afl_fixtures.csv")
    
    next_week_df = get_next_week_df(afl_data)
    game_ids_next_round = create_next_weeks_game_ids(afl_data)
    next_week_df
    
    # Append next week's games to our afl_data DataFrame
    afl_data = afl_data.append(next_week_df).reset_index(drop=True)

    # Append next week's games to match results (we need to do this for our feature creation to run)
    match_results = afl_data_cleaning_v2.get_cleaned_match_results().append(next_week_df)

    # Append next week's games to odds
    odds = (afl_data_cleaning_v2.get_cleaned_odds().pipe(lambda df: df.append(next_week_df[df.columns]))
           .reset_index(drop=True))

    features_df = afl_feature_creation_v2.prepare_afl_features(afl_data=afl_data, match_results=match_results, odds=odds)

    # Get the train df by only taking the games IDs which aren't in the next week df
    train_df = features_df[~features_df.game.isin(next_week_df.game)]

    # Get the result and merge to the feature_df
    match_results = (pd.read_csv("data/afl_match_results.csv")
                        .rename(columns={'Game': 'game'})
                        .assign(result=lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['Home.Points'] > row['Away.Points'] else 0, axis=1)))

    train_df = pd.merge(train_df,  match_results[['game', 'result']], on='game')

    train_x = train_df.drop(columns=['result'])
    train_y = train_df.result


    next_round_x = features_df[features_df.game.isin(next_week_df.game)]

    # Fit out logistic regression model - note that our predictions come out in the order of [away_team_prob, home_team_prob]

    lr_best_params = {'C': 0.01,
     'class_weight': None,
     'dual': False,
     'fit_intercept': True,
     'intercept_scaling': 1,
     'max_iter': 100,
     'multi_class': 'ovr',
     'n_jobs': 1,
     'penalty': 'l2',
     'random_state': None,
     'solver': 'newton-cg',
     'tol': 0.0001,
     'verbose': 0,
     'warm_start': False}

    feature_cols = [col for col in train_df if col.startswith('f_')]

    # Scale features
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    train_x[feature_cols] = scaler.fit_transform(train_x[feature_cols])
    
    next_round_x.loc[:, feature_cols] = scaler.transform(next_round_x[feature_cols]) # <--- THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING THE WARNING

    lr = LogisticRegression(**lr_best_params)
    lr.fit(train_x[feature_cols], train_y)
    prediction_probs = lr.predict_proba(next_round_x[feature_cols])

    modelled_home_odds = [1/i[1] for i in prediction_probs]
    modelled_away_odds = [1/i[0] for i in prediction_probs]

    # Create a predictions df
    preds_df = (next_round_x[['date', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'venue', 'game']].copy()
                   .assign(modelled_home_odds=modelled_home_odds,
                          modelled_away_odds=modelled_away_odds)
                   .pipe(pd.merge, next_week_odds, on=['home_team', 'away_team'])
                   .pipe(pd.merge, features_df[['game', 'f_elo_home', 'f_elo_away']], on='game')
                   .drop(columns='game')
               )
    return preds_df
```

Comment: By any chance does `df_copy = next_round_x.copy().loc[:, feature_cols]` and then `df_copy = scaler.transform(df_copy[feature_cols])` solve the error?

Comment: No, this throws `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars modelled_away_odds = [1/i[0] for i in prediction_probs]`

Comment: I suppose it does solve the error actually - the warning goes away, but it introduces a new one!

Comment: Change this line: ` `next_round_x = features_df[features_df.game.isin(next_week_df.game)].copy()`

Comment: This also throws `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars modelled_away_odds = [1/i[0] for i in prediction_probs]`

Comment: Pretty sure the error has nothing to do with the line I suggested, since `.copy()` does not touch your data, just creates a deep copy of your dataframe, so you're not working on a copy.

Comment: The code runs successfully in its current state (with a warning), and it throws the exception above when I made the change you suggest, so whatever your change does produces a different result than the original.

Comment: Ahh - are you talking about a different line to the one I've pointed out as throwing the error?

Comment: Got it - thanks Erfan. The warning has gone - feel free to answer below and I will accept.

Comment: Yes @ChrisMcKinnel I knew that you had to throw `.copy()` in there somehwere. I was just putting it in the wrong place.